# How can I prevent Sentry from reporting an error in javascript in the browswer?

Tags: javascript, logging, browser, error-handling, sentry

It seems like Sentry is reporting an error I intentionally swallow. Why is this? How can I tell Sentry not to report on this swallowed error?

[image: Sentry Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Sentry.init({
  ignoreErrors: ['NotSupportedError']
  // or
  ignoreErrors: [/operation is not supported/]
})
```

or with `beforeSend`

```
Sentry.init({
  beforeSend(event) {
    // or `value` instead of a `type`
    if (event.exception && event.exception.values[0].type === 'NotSupportedError') {
      return null
    }
    return event;
  }
})
```

Comment: beforeSend(event, hint) { return (hint.originalException === 'NotSupportedError') ? null : event }